# How can I store float variable to int array (C)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables

Is there a way to store `float` variable for example: PI (3.1415) to `int16_t` array, and then print it using pointers?

Comment: Yes. Of course by occupying more than one `int16_t` element of the array (two, as float has size 4). But... why? It sounds "dangerous".

Comment: You can copy the raw binary data of the `float` to an array of `char`, and then copy back into a `float`. Just about anything else will break *strict aliasing*.

Comment: With that said, what is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to copy the `float` value to an array? Why does it have to be an array of 16-bit integers? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us. Lastly please read about [the XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), as your question is one.

Comment: Please focus this question on the actual problem you intend to solve, instead of on the first thing which seemed to you to be a possible way of achieving it. I.e. I am with Some that we are looking at a XY problem question. Read that last link he provided carefully and then try to go one logical step back. Talk about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how you can do it w/ pointer casting:

```
float f = 3.14; // float -> 4 bytes
int16_t i[2];   // int16_t -> 2 x 2 bytes each

i[0] = *(((int16_t *)&f) + 0);
// store first 2 bytes of float into i[0]
// be careful here!!! endianness matters
// for little endian, use
// i[0] = *(((int16_t *)&f) + 1);

i[1] = *(((int16_t *)&f) + 1);
// store last 2 bytes of float into i[1]
// be careful here!!! endianness matters
// for little endian, use
// i[1] = *(((int16_t *)&f) + 0);

printf("%d\n", (int)i[0]);
// prints the int16_t representation 
// of the first 2 bytes of float bit pattern
printf("%d\n", (int)i[1]);
// prints the int16_t representation 
// of the last 2 bytes of float bit pattern

printf("%f\n", *((float *)&i));
// prints the float in full
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, there is possibly unaligned pointer access and always aliasing violation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : Well, you may tell the answer is off the C standards but it's not wrong. It works. Btw, I suspected that the questioner got this assignment to get used to how pointers, pointer arithmetic & endianness work. This is a better way addressing the aim of his/her assignment.

Comment: @ssd Yes you suspected correctly, so thank you! :)

Comment: @ssd no - it is Undefined Behaviour. So today it will work, but with the next version of the compiler not. Even uC programmers avoid pointer punning, Your answer is simply wrong and hopefully it will be DV as low as it deserves.

Comment: @P__J__ : I disagree. C is a language of its own. It is designed to do weird things **on purpose** & that is why operating systems and device drivers are written in C.

Comment: @ssd *`C is a language of its own`* OK if you have  **your own language C and you own compiler** then maybe it is OK - as I do not know the ssd-C. But it is not if we consider the C language (not ssd-C)

Comment: @P__J__ : Didn't mean (neither write down) that "C is a language of my own" but "a language of its own". I'm sure, you got what I meant. And, yes I know, pointer-punning is not a standard operation in C but one of the reasons C is loosely designed is those kind of non-standard operations; 'tweaks' literally. Again, whatever the comp. science lesson the questioner taking, I suspect, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTSvthW34GU&t=44m45s) part of the video (44:45 and following ~5 minutes) is the chapter s/he is currently learning.

Comment: @ssh Shame for the uni & the professor I afraid. interesting if he thinks the same now.

Answer (score 4):

Size of `float` is 4 byte, while size of `int16_t` is 2 byte.
You can use 2 x `int16_t` elements of array to store single `float`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const float float_var = M_PI;
    int16_t int16_arr[10];

    // save
    memcpy(int16_arr, &float_var, sizeof(float));

    // load
    float another_float_var;
    memcpy(&another_float_var, int16_arr, sizeof(float));

    printf("%f\n", another_float_var); 
}
```